# Linear Algebra - Using 2 Transition matrices to find the 3rd transition matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, transition-matrix

If Given the transition matrices:

$$
 P_{A \rightarrow B} \begin{bmatrix}
3 &1 \\ 5 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
 P_{B \rightarrow C} \begin{bmatrix}
7 &2 \\ 4 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
How would one determine the transition matrix of A to C?
My first intuition was to premultiply the second to the first.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the action of a matrix on a vector is represented as a left multiplication (rows by columns) of the matrix by the vector: $P \vec v$ . In this case you are right: we have
$$
P_{A\to C}=P_{B\to C}P_{A\to B}
$$